# new line when using DataOutputStream, Android

Tags: java, android

Im trying to export some data from my database to a file. I m using the `DataOutputStream` because I need the method `writeChars(String r)`.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to change the line. the `"\n"` leaves a space but its not changing the line. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to write text to a file you have chosen the wrong class. DataOuputStream.writeChars always writes characters in UTF-16BE. Use BufferedWriter or PrintWriter instead. PrintWriter.println appends a platform specific line separator to the end of the line. The line separator is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n'). E.g for Windows "\r\n", for Unix '\n' etc.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj dataoutput is for binary data! think again if you need to output a new line

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variable like `String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: Thank you.you mean like file.writeChars(newLine);.Ive also tried this way before I post the question.with this way I just get a space too.Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use this : `String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");`